# php - unable to register user when using prepared statements

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

For some reason, my code isn't registering the user when they click register. I was first using regular mysqli, and when I changed the code to a prepared statement, it didn't work. If the registration was successful, it's supposed to show a message, and it is showing the message even though the values haven't been inserted into the database.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
// variable declaration
$username = "";
$email    = "";
$errors = array();
$_SESSION['success'] = "";

// connect to database
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'cubetastic');

// REGISTER USER
if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {
  // receive all input values from the form
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $password_1 = $_POST['password_1'];
  $password_2 = $_POST['password_2'];

  // form validation: ensure that the form is correctly filled
  // I don't think this part is relevant here

  // register user if there are no errors in the form
  if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $_SESSION['verify'] = "Your account has been created, please verify it by clicking the activation link that has been sent to your email.";
    $hash = md5(rand(0,1000)); // Generate random 32 character hash and assign it to a local variable.
    // Example output: f4552671f8909587cf485ea990207f3b
    $password = md5($password_1);//encrypt the password before saving in the database

    $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, hash)
              VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $query);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's, s, s, s', $username, $email, $password, $hash);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: There's no need to use both `mysqli_real_escape_string()` and a prepared statement.

Comment: You need to read the manual on this http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php yours failed.

Comment: `$password = md5($password_1);` don't use that, it's unsafe. Use `password_hash()/password_verify()`.

Comment: Your binding parameter string should not have commas in it. It should be `$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $username, $email, $password, $hash)`

Comment: why do you have commas and spaces in your types string, don't you want `ssss` not `s, s, s, s`

Comment: `mysqli_error($db)` on the query would have thrown you something about this syntax error. Always use this during development testing and always read the official manuals; that's what they're there for.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks, I removed the escape strings.

Comment: Fred-ii-, chilliNUT and Phil, thank you for your suggestions, looks like the problem was the commas. Can one of you please answer the question so that I can accept it?

Comment: You're welcome @Cubetastic (as per requested), I posted something for you below, *cheers*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manual on [`mysqli_stmt_bind_param()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) clearly shows no commas are used in order to state which data types to pass as the arguments and in conjunction with that, the number of binds.

I have to state that MD5 is no longer considered to be a safe hashing method, especially in a live environment.

Use both `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` respectively and make sure that the (password) column is long enough to accomodate its length.

The manual suggests to use a minimum of 60 length, yet states that a length of 255 is a good bet.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

As I (also) stated in comments: Use [`mysqli_error($db)`](http://php.net/mysqli_error) on the query. That would have thrown you something about this syntax error. Always use this during development testing and always read the official manuals; that's what they're there for.

Comment: Thank you, Fred! I tried using `password_hash()/password_verify();`, but it didn't work! And I also added `mysqli_error(db)` into my code.

Comment: @Cubetastic You're welcome. You would need to post a new question for this though. I'm sure someone will be able to help and maybe myself later on, I just have a lot of things to do right now. Ping me back if and when you do post a new question and I'll be glad to look at it.

Comment: Well, after doing a considerable amount of research, I have posted my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46407662/php-password-verify-not-working-even-though-both-values-are-same).